# AH01630: client denied by server configuration, redirected from one virtualhost to another

Tags: apache, flask, wsgi, certbot

### Summary

I've read through a crapload of Google results and stackoverflow questions but can't figure this out. The core issue seem to be:

- Basic setup is `Apache/2.4.10`, `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 4.3.0-1` and flask `1.0.2`
- This was working fine before I setup HTTPS using certbot
- There are two subdomains setup in separate `.conf` files using virtualhosts. The .conf files are identical apart from the directories and project names/URLs
- **The Apache logs indicate that request is somehow redirected from `project_2` URL to `project_1` WSGI script, and I don't understand why**
- If anyone could please point me in the right direction I'd be eternally grateful

### Apache logs:

`[ssl:debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(243): AH02034: Initial (No.1) HTTPS request received for child 67 (server project_2.domain.com:443)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
[authz_core:error] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/username/projects/project_1/app/run_site.wsgi
[ssl:debug]  ssl_engine_kernel.c(243): AH02034: Subsequent (No.2) HTTPS request received for child 68 (server project_2.domain.com:443), ref$
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of Require all denied: denied, referer: https://www.project_2.domain.com/
[authz_core:debug]  mod_authz_core.c(809): AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied, referer: https://www.project_2.domain.com/
authz_core:error]  AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/username/projects/project_1/app/run_site.wsgi, referer: https://www.project_2.domain.com/`

### Apache .conf files

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/project_2.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project_2 user=username group=username threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/username/projects/project_2/run_site.wsgi"

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project_2.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.project_2.domain.com

        <Directory "/home/username/projects/project_2/">
                WSGIProcessGroup project_2
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIScriptReloading On

                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/notifier_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/notifier_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.project_2.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =project_2.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/project_2-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName project_2.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.project_2.domain.com

        <Directory "/home/username/projects/project_2/">
                WSGIProcessGroup project_2
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIScriptReloading On

                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_2_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/project_2_access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_2.domain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.project_2.domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### sudo apachectl -S:

`VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server project_1.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project_1-le-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost project_1.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project_1-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.project_1.domain.com
         port 443 namevhost project_2.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project_2-le-ssl.conf:2)
                 alias www.project_2.domain.com
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server project_1.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project_1.conf:4)
         port 80 namevhost project_1.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project_1.conf:4)
                 alias www.project_1.domain.com
         port 80 namevhost project_2.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/project_2.conf:4)
                 alias www.project_2.domain.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33`

Comment: I think this has something to do with bringing the definition of `WSGIScriptAlias` outside of the virtualhost (which is necessary so there are no duplicates), but I feel this might duplicate the configuration between the different virtualhosts causing a redirect from `project_2` to `project_1` since they both have a `WSGIScriptAlias` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out my mistake. When I was setting up certbot I moved both these lines outside the virtual host:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project_2 user=username group=username threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/username/projects/project_2/run_site.wsgi"
```

This lead to two `WSGIScriptAlias` lines in both my `.conf` files, one was overriding the other. What fixed this is bringing the `WSGIScriptAlias` inside the virtual host in both scripts `project_1.conf` and `project_2.conf`, as well as adding it manually back into `project_1-le-ssl.conf` and `project_2-le-ssl.conf`

Resulting `.conf` example:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project_2 user=username group=username threads=5

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project_2.domain.com
        ServerAlias www.project_2.domain.com

        WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/username/projects/project_2/run_site.wsgi"

        <Directory "/home/username/projects/project_2/">
                WSGIProcessGroup project_2
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                WSGIScriptReloading On

                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/notifier_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/notifier_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.project_2.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =project_2.domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```